# How to add some custom value with a serializer existing value?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that return a (label) date and (value) the total registered user of corresponding date in a range of date.Now I want to add the value to 0 for the date those have no registed user and return this serialize.
Here is my serializer's output

```
{
    "report_title": "Registration Report",
    "total": 5,
    "data": [
      {
        "label": "2017-07-21",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "2017-07-24",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "2017-08-04",
        "value": 1
      }
    ],
    "start_date": "2017-07-07",
    "end_date": "2017-08-07"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

1. Instead of modifying serializer's data, try modifying it before serialization happens
2. Do convert to python object by json.loads(serialized_data) and modify

   ```
   import json
   data = json.loads(<your_serialized_data>)
   data["start_date"] = <Assign_watever_value_you_want>
   ```